# How to use a custom processor directive in scriptcs?

Tags: scriptcs

I've written a custom processor directive for scriptcs based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406109/scriptcs-hosting-advantages-over-roslyn/18442295#18442295), but I can't figure out how to make it available for use. I just get the error "Preprocessor directive expected". I'm guessing there's some special way of registering the directive, but I haven't found it yet.

Edit: I added some info to [this issue on github](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/issues/401).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register the line pre-processor with the services builder and in order to get that done you would need to use a module as explained [here](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/issues/583#issuecomment-36216981).

Unfortunately right now there is not a lot of documentation available on using modules (we plan to improve that some time in the future), but the previous link provides a link to [this sample project](https://github.com/scriptcs-contrib/scriptcs-sample-module) which you can use as guidance.

For module development you don't need to install the module globally. You can take advantage of the feature described [here](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/pull/537). You will need to install the module using `-g` once you want to use it for real.

Comment: if you run with -debug flag you can load the module from bin relative to your script. for example scriptcs my.csx -debug -modules modulename

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. After I get my hands dirty with it, I wouldn't mind contributing some documentation.

Comment: @ryan.rousseau That would be awesome! :)

Comment: @ryan.rousseau it definitely would be!

Comment: I might be missing something. I created a ExecLinePreprocessor that inherits from DirectiveLineProcessor.  I also created ExecModule which implements IModule. See [the gist here](https://gist.github.com/ryanrousseau/10659138).

The module loads correctly, but it still doesn't find the line processor. I'm looking through the source and I can't find the connection between LineProcessors on IModuleConfiguration and the LineProcessors on ScriptServicesBuilder that is passed to RuntimeServices yet.  I'll keep looking tonight, but if someone has a hint, that would be great.

Comment: @khellang developed the line pre-processor feature so he is probably the person best suited to answer