# What is the different between scriptcs and roslyn scripting?

Tags: roslyn, scriptcs

I would like to know the difference between Roslyn scripting and scriptcs? I understand that scriptcs is built on top on Roslyn but would like to understand what the extras are that scriptcs providing to me as a developer?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest advantage is that the is out of the box support for ScriptPacks via NuGet.

There are additional benefits such as hosting scripts and dynamic loading/line mode processing as explained the the accepted answer here:  [scriptcs hosting - Advantages over Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406109/scriptcs-hosting-advantages-over-roslyn)